# pandas check conditions inside a subset to obtain values

Tags: python, pandas

The following data set has containers with specific items that have a specific priority.

```
container item_No  Priority
1          123      A
1          124      B
1          142      D
2          516      C
2          142      D
3          516      C
3          124      B
3          123      A
```

I would like to have a dataset where, if the container has any items of priority 'A' then the priority level for the entire container is 'A'.  If there is no A, check for B and then the priority level is 'B'. If there is no 'B', check for 'C'. so on and so forth...

I would like the following df as an output.

```
container  Priority
1            A
2            C
3            A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert column for ordered categoricals with specify order and then aggregate `min`:

```
df['Priority'] = pd.Categorical(df['Priority'], ordered=True, categories=['A','B','C','D'])

df = df.groupby('container', as_index=False)['Priority'].min()
print (df)
   container Priority
0          1        A
1          2        C
2          3        A
```

If working with letters like `ABCD` in with default order, solution is simplier:

```
df = df.groupby('container', as_index=False)['Priority'].min()
```

Comment: That's good to know, I just made up the A B C D for example sake, the priority labels are actually arbritary.